# Differing results from choice and choices in python random?

Tags: python

I would have suspected the following code return comparable results:

```
import random

random.seed(765)
x = random.choices(range(34), k=100)

random.seed(765)
y = [random.choice(range(34)) for _ in range(100)]
```

But when we compare

```
>>> x[:5]
[1, 8, 9, 31, 29]
>>> y[:5]
[2, 30, 15, 26, 17]
```

clearly `x` is not equivalent to `y`.

I suspect that I a missing something obvious, but assumed the sequence set by the seed would have returned the same 100 values, regardless of choice vs choices with k = 100.

Comment: well, the choice is expected to be random. Even two subsequent calls to `random.choices` will return different results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

> For a given seed, the `choices()` function with equal weighting typically produces a different sequence than repeated calls to [`choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). The algorithm used by `choices()` uses floating point arithmetic for internal consistency and speed. The algorithm used by `choice()` defaults to integer arithmetic with repeated selections to avoid small biases from round-off error.

Comment: Which implicitly implies that `choice` and `choices` do **not** use the same algorithms and using one inside a loop is not equivalent to calling the other with `k` argument.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure that this was the case, and 1000% assumed they were functionally equivalent if k=1 was called on choices.